# Is a singleton in a p-adic space connected?

Tags: functions, p-adic-number-theory

I want to use a theorem with a p-adic space:

The image by a continuous epimorphism of a connected space, is itself connected.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the fact that every p-adic field is totally disconnected, is a fairly major stumbling block, rendering the theorem nullipotent in p-adic spaces.

BUT... I'm confused by this:

Am I right in thinking that a singleton is connected?

The rule I have is that a space is connected if it cannot be represented as the union of two or more disjoint non-empty open subsets.

Clearly a singleton cannot be represented as the union of two or more disjoint non-empty subsets, irrespective of whether or not they're open, so must by this rule be connected.

Then we can conclude there can be no continuous, noninjective epimorphisms in a padic space which project multiple points down to any singleton.

Comment: You didn’t specify what the domain of the functions in question might be.

Comment: @Lubin good point. I say a padic space but I'm actually thinking about the 5-rough natural numbers with the 2 adic metric. The limit points of the Collatz graph through these numbers are connected (graph-wise - i.e. are ordered by the directed graph) by which I want to conclude the graph itself is connected (graph-wise).

Comment: @Lubin ...although I think I have another argument coming out of being sequentially continuous which gets the job done, but I'd be keen to learn anything you may have to add.

Comment: Well, needless to say, there are plenty of nonconstant continuous maps $\Bbb Q_p\to\Bbb Q_p$. In essence, every $p$-adic field is (something like) a Cantor set, though $\Bbb Q_p$ itself is not compact. This means, for instance, that there are plenty of nonconstant continuous maps $\Bbb Q_p\to\Bbb Q_q$ for $p\ne q$ as well, though in this case, they’re of rather less interest for algebraic purposes (not ring homomorphisms, for instance).

Comment: A warning, though: one would be fairly sure that graphwise connectivity is not topological connectivity.

Comment: @Lubin thanks I'll keep an eye out for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singletons are connected in every space. A space is called totally disconnected if the singletons are the only connected subspaces. What follows is that a continuous map from a connected space $X$ to a totally disconnected space $Y$ is constant; in particular, it's non-injective unless the domain $X$ was a singleton to begin with.